# converting date parameter to simpledate format using iReport

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a `startDate` and an `endDate` as an input parameters.
This parameters are used in the query say:

```sql
SELECT * FROM patientRecords 
WHERE patientRecords.dateOfdischarge BETWEEN $P{startDate} AND $P{endDate}
```

Now, since the `startDate` and `endDate` are the parameters which are passed to the `JasperReports`.

I have to ensure that they are in `mm/dd/yyyy` Date format.

How do I go about converting the input parameter to this format using `iReport`?

Answer (score 1):

U can try change the patern from propertise>textfield propertise or u can try this to_char(tablename.fieldname, 'mm/dd/yyyy') as fieldname

Answer (score 0):

Try this format it will work if you are using Mysql database

date_column_name between date_format($P{start_date},'%Y-%m-%d') and date_format($P{end_date},'%Y-%m-%d')
date_column_name between date_format($P{start_date},'%Y-%m-%d') and date_format($P{end_date},'%Y-%m-%d')

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I'll directly send these parameters as in the format you said from Java. If that not possible for you and wanna be sure, you can use EL for formatting as well such as Java or Groovy in the iReport