# Date/Time Input Parameters

Tags: mysql, jasper-reports

I am using two **date time** parameters in the report. When I use the same parameters in the query, no results are shown. Moreover if I use **date** parameters then the results are shown but not all records are shown.

I also executed the same query (with date time) in *MySQL* and the results are shown, I think there is no mistake in the query.

I tried many things. The query is some what like :

```sql
SELECT * FROM abc WHERE datetime BETWEEN 
  date_format($P{fromdate}, '%d-%c-%y 00:00:00') 
  AND date_format($P{todate}, '%d-%c-%y 23:59:59')
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [converting date parameter to simpledate format using iReport](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351165/converting-date-parameter-to-simpledate-format-using-ireport) & [How to pass Date as parameter to jasper report](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12172711/876298)

Comment: What type of this two parameters? Did you check the resulted query string with help of *textField*, for example?

Comment: To print the query string ,what should I do?

Comment: You can add the *textField* with your expression (`SELECT * FROM abc WHERE datetime BETWEEN date_format($P{fromdate}, '%d-%c-%y 00:00:00') AND date_format($P{todate}, '%d-%c-%y 23:59:59')`) to the *Title* band, for example. Or you can make *log4j* settings. And you can find the resulted query in *iReport output* window.

Comment: I think someone is trying to downvote my all questions : )

Answer (score 0):

Try without data_format function to check whether error in query or in parameters.

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM abc WHERE datetime BETWEEN 
        $P{fromdate} AND $P{todate}
```

Comment: I tried this as well along with date/time parameters & date parameters. It worked for date parameter but all records were not shown.And with date/time no record was displayed.

Comment: with date/time no record was displayed means are you getting any error?

Comment: I changed my query & it worked out properly. The query used now is :

     SELECT * 
     FROM abc WHERE datetime BETWEEN between CONCAT($P{fromdate},' ' , '00:00:00') and CONCAT($P{todate} ,' ' ,'23:59:59')

Comment: What is the datatype of fromdate and todate values in database?

Comment: DateTime in database & Date in Jasper iReport.

Comment: NOTE: going between 00:00:00 and 23:59:59 will miss out the transactions which occured after 23:59:59 and 00:00:00.